# Can you define defs when using a series of symbols in an SVG element?

Tags: svg

I am trying to define defs for one of the svgs I am using. The set up is currently we have a load of reusable icons as symbols in SVG tags:

```
<svg>
  <symbol id="id" viewBox="...">
    <path fill="#..." d="..."/>
    <path fill="#..." d="..."/>
  </symbol>

  <symbol id="id" viewBox="...">
    <path fill="#..." d="..."/>
    <path fill="#..." d="..."/>
  </symbol>

  <symbol id="id" viewBox="...">
    <path fill="#..." d="..."/>
    <path fill="#..." d="..."/>
  </symbol>
</svg>
```

To display one of the icons:

```
<svg>
  <use xlinkHref='#id'></use>
</svg>
```

I have an icon which has a gradient, specified in defs tags, but I'm not sure how that works with this method of using SVGs. Is the only way to specify the defs tags in the use block of code:

```
<svg>
  <defs>
    <linearGradient ...>
      <stop stopColor=“#... " offset=“0%“></stop>
      <stop stopColor=“#...” offset=“100%“></stop>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <use xlinkHref='#id'></use>
</svg>
```

Or can you put it in the same location where the symbols are defined for re-use, so you don't have to re-specify every time you use the icon?

Thank you

Comment: you could make the linearGradient a sibling of the symbols. You shouldn't make it a child of any of the symbols though.

Comment: How do you link the linear gradient to the symbols if they are siblings?

Comment: The same way as if they weren't.

Comment: Not sure how to exactly. Sorry can you explain?

Comment: Nothing would change. Not sure how to make that any clearer or what exactly your concern is.

Comment: I tried the linear gradient within defs as a sibling of the symbol and the svg didn't display.

Comment: I dont know why as you've not shown me. Edit the question. I assume all your id values are unique. That's not clear from the question where you reuse 'id'

Comment: A [mcve] would help here.